# How do I add a top padding to a background image in css?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I tried adding a padding top with numerous pixel values in the styling but the image padding with respect to the web page refused to change. ie padding-top: 5px; .. An excerpt of my code is given below:-

```
<div class="row pb-5 mt-4" style="background-color: rgba(3, 31, 45, 0.5);">
          style="background-image: url('images/image1.jpg'); 
          background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: center; background-size: cover; 
          position: relative; border-radius: 10px 0 0 10px; padding-top: 5px;">
</div>
```

Comment: You have typos in your markup, which I'm sure isn't related to the issue. Please correct if so. You have a closing '>' at the end of the first line and a duplicate 'style' attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Padding will only be applied to the element to which you're adding the background, but not to the background image itself. It seems to be that what you want to play with is `background-position`.

You currently have `background-position: center;`

Try changing that to `background-position: center 20px;`

See: https://www.w3schools.com/CSSref/pr_background-position.asp for more examples

Comment: Great, thanks! worked like a charm :) though the only problem is that it removed the border-radiuses i had added.

Comment: Please provide a screenshot or link to the minimum reproducible example to help better understand the desired end result.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do this by adding style attribute:

```
background-position: 0 5px;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

Comment: Thanks, It worked but it removed the border radiuses I had added. What could be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
      background-position-y: 5px!important;
      background-position: center;
```

Answer (score 1):

In this case the solution is the `background-position` as the others mentioned.

`border-radius` problem is normal. Please check the code below to understand. Think that your div is a rectangle and you have your background image on it. When you play with `background-position` you move the image but not the div itself. So, radius property stay in its place and does not change.

```css
        html, body{

            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
        }

        * {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }

        .outer{
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
            background-color: rgba(3, 31, 45, 0.5);
            padding-top: 5%;
        }

        .inner-with-bg{
            width: 50%;
            height: 50%;
            margin: 0 auto;
            background-image: url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b6/Image_created_with_a_mobile_phone.png);
            background-position: 30px 10px;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-size: cover;
            border-radius: 60px 0 0 60px;
            border: 1px solid red;
        }
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner-with-bg">          
  </div>
</div>
```